# using JavaScript how do I overwrite a 2D array in a preexisting csv file from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, database, csv

I am planning on using a csv file to store a simple table.
, for example like this

```
var table = [["jack","john","bob"],
 [15,19,20]
 ["talkative","boring","funny"],
 ... ,
 ... ,
 ... ,
 ... ,
 ["science","math","english"]]
```

i am looking for a way to replace all the data inside the preexisting csv file with **var table**

```
//after replacing all the data inside a csv file with var table

jack,john,bob
15,19,20
talkative,boring,funny
a,b,c
x,y,z
g,h,i
science,math,english
```

or some thing like cleaning the csv file completely and then storing this var table inside it

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: yes i did look it up but everything i came across is based on a json array i want it to be exactly in 2d array not in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use `writeFile` in write mode. for your reference:

```
'use strict'

const { parse } = require('json2csv');
const { writeFile } = require('fs')

function convertJsonCsv() {
    const data = [
        ["jack", "john", "bob"],
        [15, 19, 20],
        ["talkative", "boring", "funny"],
        ["science", "math", "english"]
    ]

    const csv = parse(data)

    writeFile('./path/of/the/file.csv', csv, {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        flag: 'w'
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    });

}
```

Comment: i did use this but i am getting an error (SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Comment: have you tried the existing script. there is no use of `import` here. can you share your file code where you are trying to integrate this code. @DoctorPinocchio

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the array using csv-parse like

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
    // [
    //   { NAME: 'Daffy Duck', AGE: '24' },
    //   { NAME: 'Bugs Bunny', AGE: '22' }
    // ]
  });
```

2. Modify your array within your script
3. Convert your final array to CSV Format using the code below

```
const arr = [["My","Lovelly","Array"],["My","Lovelly","Array"]]
const arrayToCSV = (arr, delimiter = ',', rowdelimiter = '\n') =>
  {
    let rows = arr.length // returns rows
    let cols = arr[0].length ; // returns col
    let str = ""
    for(let i=0;i<rows;i++){
      for(let j=0;j<cols;j++){
       if(j==cols-1){
         str+=arr[i][j]
         str+=rowdelimiter
       }else{
         str+=arr[i][j]
         str+=delimiter
       }
      }
    }
    return str
    // arr.map(v => v.map(x => `"${x}"`).join(delimiter)).join('\n');
    
  }
  const csvstring = arrayToCSV(arr,",")
  console.log(csvstring)
```

4. Then write the formatted CSV to the file

Hope that is helpful

**EDIT : Full Example :-**

CSV File : data.csv

```
name,age
John Doe,27
Adam Linux,20
```

NodeJs Script : index.js // or any name

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

const arrayToCSV = (arr, delimiter = ',', rowdelimiter = '\n') => {
    let rows = arr.length // returns rows
    let str = "name,age\n"
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        str += arr[i].name
        str += delimiter

        // row delimiter after the last parameter only
        str += arr[i].age
        str += rowdelimiter
    }
    return str
}

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log(results);
        results[0].name = "John Doe"
        results[0].age = "27"
        results.push({
            name: "Adam Linux",
            age: "20"
        })
        console.log(results);
        const csvstring = arrayToCSV(results, ",")
        console.log("csv String : " + csvstring)
        fs.writeFile('data.csv', csvstring, {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            flag: 'w'
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });

    });
```

Comment: can you also show how to write this csv string to the file ( step : 4)

Comment: Ok, I'll do edit the answer to add a full example

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs');

const arrayData = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  ['one', 'two', 'three']
];

const stringData = arrayData.reduce((accOne, array) => {
  const str = array.reduce((accTwo, item, index) => {
    return accTwo + `${item}${index < array.length - 1 ? ',' : ''}`
  }, '');
  return accOne + `${str}\n`;
}, '');

fs.writeFileSync('test-report.csv', stringData);
```